# AssertionError when add a TimeDistributed(Dense) layer in Keras sequence model

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am building a RNN to predict a many to one question.

```
#Input_X:
[
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
]

#Input_Y:
[
11,
12
]
#Each number represent a category

X=np.reshape(Input_X,(len(Input_X), 10, 1))

y=np.utils.to_catgeorical(Input_Y)  #one hot encode,
```

My model setup:

```
#####This works 
model=Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape(X.shape[1], X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentrophy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X,y, ........)
```

I want to try the TimeDistributed(Dense) layer instead, for example: https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/. So I changed above to below:

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape(X.shape[1], X.shape[2])))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax')))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentrophy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X,y, ........)
```

I am getting a AssertionError. Which report the matrix size is not what expected.
What steps I missed?

Comment: time distributed dense is really for many to many

Comment: if I modify my my input_y to be length of 2 for each of the output. I still get the AssertionError

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add `return_sequences=True` to the LSTM cell

````
```
model=Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, input_shape(X.shape[1], X.shape[2])))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax')))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentrophy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X,y, ........)
````

```

Comment: Nope, when using `return_sequences=True` I get `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_11 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (2, 50)`

Answer (score 0):

`return_sequences=True` works for me.

In the OP's question, y.shape is (2,1) which has 2 samples and only 1 feature , so it's not suited for Many to Many model.